# In what case the Windows edge browser could get the full file path of a file?

Tags: javascript, html, microsoft-edge

I'm debugging a freaky bug.

We saw the server side returned an exception with this file information

> > > C:\Users\me\Desktop\TheCover.jpg

Basically, we uploaded this file and the server will do a bunch of validations.

However, when I drilled into FileList and dig the File object information.

It only contains the fileName from the browser, there's no way to get the file path of the upload file.

How come the service could return a file path in the error message?

Any idea? Actually, I think this is the root cause because we're not expecting to provide a full file path instead of a file name.

Any idea or direction? Thanks

## Update

This bug is difficult to show it in a sample code.

So far, it's only reproducible in native windows ENV with IE edge browser (Chrome and firefox work well). (Mac parrallels won't be able to reproduce this bug)

Comment: Due to security concerns, depending on the browser you may not get the full path, or specifically get a fake path. Recommendation is to ignore the path and just deal with the image and the file name as you need.

Comment: As far as I know no modern browser (where "modern" means since about 1999) sends the full file path when posting a form with a `<input type=file>` field. This can be confirmed by checking the actual content of the HTTP request involved.

Comment: IIRC IE before Edge did expose this info from `HTMLInput.value`, but I just tested in Edge and it returns a fake path like other browsers (`C:\fakepath\<yourfilename>`) Are you sure that was from edge?

Comment: We tried to make a test with Microsoft Edge 44.18362.1.0 using HTML file input and notice that it shows the fake path. If possible than try to provide more information about the issue like which exact version of MS Edge browser causing this issue? Which is the OS build version? If there is any sample code or steps to produce the issue than please try to provide it. It can help to narrow down the issue.

Comment: I'd like to provide more info. However, it's an NDA and hugh project. I can only know the server return as a error message with whole file path and as far as I know, we're simply upload using JS file object.

Comment: As we already tested the issue with the simple sample code and issue is not producible. I understand your concern about the large project. If possible than you can try to create a simple sample like it is in your actual site. it also can be helpful if it is able to reproduce the issue. It can give some more information which can help to narrow down the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are confusing the file input display with something returned by the server. In Edge, the file input display does show the full local path of the file you have selected, but the JavaScript code cannot access this value. As an example, try running this snippet in Edge and selecting a file:

```js
document.querySelector('#fileInput').addEventListener('change', e => console.log(e.target.value))
```

```html
<input type="file" id="fileInput">
```